# Am I stuck with forcing fixed image size for image tags?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, responsive-design

I have a website that contains a side bar and sometimes an image of a very large size (about 800 pixels wide) but I scripted the code so that if a screen resolution is too small, the image shrinks and scales into the small space perfectly according to multiple browsers I tested the site on. I tested the site with the demo version of sortsite by powermapper at:

```
http://try.powermapper.com/Demo/
```

It then goes on to complain that "Omitting IMG WIDTH or HEIGHT attributes means page text jumps about as images load.   Usability.gov 14:3"

I understand that and I try to include those attributes, the image does not scale correctly.

This is the CSS I use on the image itself to scale it if I had a monitor with a max screen width of 800 pixels:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){#X IMG{width: 100%}}
```

I specify 600px because I reserved 200 pixels for the sidebar.

I don't think javascript will be an answer because during the page load, the image placeholder will jump to the new size, and if I placed the code near the beginning, it will delay the the rest of the page from loading somewhat.

I was also thinking using div tags and setting the background to the image, but the problem there is that users won't be able to save it and the rest of the images on my site are part of a CSS sprite sheet.

I also am looking for a solution that will work with as many web browsers as possible even if javascript is disabled.

Any ideas for an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule, while correct, went out the window when responsive design came into being:

> Omitting IMG WIDTH or HEIGHT attributes means page  text jumps about
>   as images load. Usability.gov 14:3

If you're always going to be using a given aspect ratio, then you can set up your code as below. If you set your `width` and `height` attributes on your `img` tag and you set `max-width: 100%` (or similar) in your CSS, as people often do when developing responsive sites, then your text will still jump around when the image loads, because it's initial height will be what you specify in your markup, and then when the image loads, the browser will maintain the aspect ratio required for `max-width: 100%` to work and end up shrinking the height - so that doesn't really help you adhere to your usability rule either.

```css
.img { 
    background-size: cover; 
    background: center no-repeat;
  }

.ar {
  height:0;
  padding: 0 0 56.25% /* 16:9 aspect ratio */
}
```

```html
<div class="img" style="background-image: url(https://placekitten.com/g/500/500);">
  <div class="ar"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Ok, I kinda thought some tools are obsolete. I'll have to find newer tools. Thanks tho.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the width and height and then just adjusting width and height with your media queries (rather than max-width and percent width). You shouldn't encounter any scaling problems then.

Comment: dlsso, If I do that, then people with small screens will complain about horizontal scrolling.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood your requirements. I was suggesting that you reduce the size at the point where you would otherwise get horizontal scrolling. However, that does not work if you need it to be 100% width at all resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){#X IMG{width: 100%}}
```

This means that IMG will have full width of it's first parent. That parent might not be X element. Are you sure you want that?
Example:

```
<div id='X'>
    <div><div><div><div>
         <img src=''>
    </div></div></div></div>
</div>
```

If you are trying to fix x:y img ratio that put `height:auto;` after `width:100%;` 
Calculate `width` or `height` and always use `auto` for other property to preserve image scaling.